# App crashes when user starts typing in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift

I have a UISearchBar set up in a tableview with core data. When the user begins to type in the search bar the app crashes on the first letter. The error I get is `(lldb)`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

Seems like my problem is with `filteredQuotes = qs.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate!)` but not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.(when I comment out this line the app doesn't crash - but search doesn't either work)

```
//
//  KeepTableViewController.swift
//  Quotey
//
//  Created by Mordechai Levi on 11/25/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Martini. All rights reserved.
//


import UIKit
import CoreData


class KeepTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var filteredQuotes = [AnyObject]()
    var keptQuotes = [NSManagedObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.showsScopeBar = true

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        getCoreData()


        searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }


    func getCoreData(){

        var appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var req : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "KeptQuotes")

        var error : NSError?

        let fetchedResults = context.executeFetchRequest(req, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?

        if let results = fetchedResults {

            keptQuotes = results

        }else{

            println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")

        }

        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    @IBAction func cancelPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) //dismisses the freakin view
    }

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {

        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
    if !keptQuotes.isEmpty {

        return 1

    }else{

    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, 180, 300))
    label.text = "Here is where quotes that you love will show up. To love a quote swipe a quote to the right."
    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.573, green: 0.6, blue: 0.627, alpha: 1)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-Medium", size: 17)
    //label.sizeToFit()

    tableView.backgroundView = label
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None


    }
    return 0

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.

        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {

            return filteredQuotes.count

        }else{

            return keptQuotes.count

    }

    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : QuoteyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as QuoteyTableViewCell

        var entry : NSManagedObject

        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView{

            entry = filteredQuotes[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject

        }else{

            entry = keptQuotes[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject!

        }

        cell.authorLabel.text = entry.valueForKey("author") as String!
        cell.quoteTextLabel.text = entry.valueForKey("quote") as String!

        cell.quoteTextLabel.sizeToFit()
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        return cell
    }



    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {

        var qs : NSArray = keptQuotes

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "quote contains[c] %@ OR author contains[c] %@", searchText, searchText)

        filteredQuotes = qs.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate!)
        println(filteredQuotes)


    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {

        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
        return true
    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {

        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text)
        return true
    }

}
```

[image: Also getting this.]

Comment: can you please give more details about error you getting?

Comment: @BaSha  in my console I get an (lldb) and a Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT on 0x1002d2528: brk #1

Comment: @BaSha just updated with more detailed report on the error

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the UISearchBar delegate but you haven't created any UISearchBarDelegate methods such as `searchBar:textDidChange:`. The crash likely occurs when a delegate method call is attempted.

Comment: Just added `searchBar:textDidChange`, still crashes :/

Comment: Can you provide the console log from Xcode? Then we can see where the app is crashing exactly.

Comment: All I get in the console is `(lldb)`

Comment: Now getting a Thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint on `0x1001b42cc:  brk    #1`. any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I figured out the problem - I'm just not sure what the solution is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465082/custom-uitableviewcell-causing-uisearchbar-to-crash

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue for 2 days. Since I don't know what to do as I tried 10 different solutions but it didn't worked

### I don't know if its related to you. Kindly check it as it worked for me.

If your application crashes on :

```
yourTableView.reloadData()
```

### Then use below solution otherwise skip below steps

**Note** `UITableView's` `reloadSections` instead of `reloadData`

```
yourTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

Here reload section which is need according to requirement